# Path always goes absolute when autocompleting if a dir has a space in its name

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I do the following with bash 5.0.17:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ mkdir 'A B'
$ touch 'A B/C.txt'
$ ls A\ B/C<TAB>
```

I want the last to autocomplete to `ls A\ B/C.txt` (relative), but it instead autocompletes to `ls /tmp/A\ B/C.txt` (absolute).  Is there any way to make it autocomplete to a relative path?

This is for working with third-party software which hardcodes directory names including spaces, so simply not using spaces in directory names isn't an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like this behaviour comes from having `direxpand` enabled. You probably have this in your bashrc:

```
shopt -s direxpand
```

You will need to remove that line or change it to `shopt -u direxpand`. Unfortunately, this means you lose the other benefits of direxpand (personally I have it enabled because I don't like `$` being escaped by tab-completion).

Comment: So there's no way to force the `direxpand` option to keep relative paths?  Too bad.

Comment: Yeah, not that I know of, sorry. You could raise it as a feature request in bug-bash mailing list, but I'm not sure how keen they would be to implement it.